# PowerShell. Как экранировать символ?

Tags: powershell, char, реестр

Есть код добавляющий параметр в реестр:

`New-ItemProperty -Path 'путь к ветке реестра' -Name 'название параметра' -Value 'значение' -PropertyType 'String'`

Значение должно содержать символы `'` или `"`.

Пример значения: `123'djkldjl'23214'hfkfhkf'64734683`

При использовании символа `'` ошибка парсинга команды. А при использовании `"` данные символы удаляются из строки.

Такой вариант не помогает: `\"` и `\'`. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: ставьте вместо одного символа `'` два символа `''` не путать с двойной кавычкой

Answer (score 4):

Строки, заключенные в одиночные кавычки, интерпретируются PowerShell дословно; строки в двойных кавычках допускают использование управляющих последовательностей, предваряемых в данном случе символом обратной одиночной кавычки `` ` ``. Иначе говоря:

```
'строка дословно`a'
```

выведет в окно хоста PowerShell:

```
строка дословно`a
```

в то время как:

```
"строка не выведет управляющую последовательность`a"
```

выведет в хост:

```
строка не выведет управляющую последовательность
```

и подаст сигнал на системный динамик. Проще говоря, символ обратной одиночной кавычки заменяет обратный слэш перед управляющими последовательностями и применяется для экранирования символов в строках, обрамленных двойными кавычками, а также используется для разбиения и переноса длинных команд.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете выполнить экранирование в если будете использовать для строк двойные кавычки «"», например:

```
"Выделить `"эту фразу кавычками`""
```

Результат

```
Выделить "эту фразу кавычками"
```